# Period of linear vs nonlinear pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I think I have an idea of how to do the problem but am not 100% sure. The question is:

**(a)** From the equation: $$T(E)=2\sqrt\frac{L}{g} \int_0^1 \frac{du}{u^\frac{1}{2}(1-u)^{\frac{1}{2}}[1-\frac{E(1-u)}{2g}]^\frac{1}{2}}$$ where $$u=1-\frac{g}{E}(1-cos \theta )$$

show that a nonlinear pendulum has a longer period than a linearized pendulum.
**(b)** Show that $\frac{dT}{dE} > 0 $. Briefly describe a physical interpretation of this result.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 So I'm thinking I should derive the E equation for both a linear pendulum and non-linear pendulume (i.e E=$\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}kx_o^2$. Then plug them in and solve and see which one gives the bigger $T(E)$ for part **(a)**. Don't know if that is the correct way to do it. 
 Then for part **(b)**, I just take the derivative of $T(E)$ and show that it's $>0$. But I don't know the *physical interpretation* of this result.

Comment: Your T(E) integral equation is actually derived from the energy equation for a nonlinear pendulum so you don't need to rederive it.

Comment: The period for a linear pendulum is $T= 2\pi \sqrt{l/g}$. So you want to show that this integral is larger than that. One way would be to expand the integrand as a series.

Comment: As far as the physical interpretation from part (b). Consider that $T$ is the period and the derivative of $T$ with respect to $E$ tells us how the period changes with the energy. If this derivative is positive what happens to $T$ when we increase the energy of the pendulum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding (a): the period of linear pendulum is
$$2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$$
and $T(E)$ is greater than that because 
$$
 \int_0^1 \frac{du}{u^\frac{1}{2}(1-u)^{\frac{1}{2}}[1-\frac{E(1-u)}{2g}]^\frac{1}{2}} >  \int_0^1 \frac{du}{u^\frac{1}{2}(1-u)^{\frac{1}{2}}} =\pi
$$
Here the last integral can be "evaluated" geometrically, by recognizing it as the arclength of the semicircle with diameter $[0,1]$. Or just do trig substitution.

For part (b), differentiate with respect to $E$ under the integral sign. You don't need to evaluate the resulting integrand; the fact that it contains a positive function is enough for conclusion. Physical interpretation: the period of nonlinear pendulum increases with amplitude. (Amplitude increases with energy, of course.)

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your answer fully. Why exactly are you setting that inequality? I understand that the RHS of the inequality is gotten when you take $E=0$ and when you actually take the integral you get $\pi$ but I don't really understand how writing that inequality answers the question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JohnBernal Edited in the formula for period of linear pendulum, in case you've forgotten that one.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really slow at getting these things to click for me. So let me see if I can break it down for myself and maybe you can see where I'm going wrong. So basically the $T(E)$ equation is derived in the book and it represents the period of a nonlinear pendulum. The question is asking us to show that the period of a nonlinear is greater than the period of a linear. So to do that we set the inequality. I guess what I'm not getting is why the RHS represents the period of a linear pendulum. Like I said, I know how you got it, by setting $E=0$, but what does it represent exactly?

Comment: @JohnBernal You are asked to prove that something is bigger the period of linear pendulum.  Does this make you think  *I wish I remembered what the period of linear pendulum is*? For me, it does. So I strained my memory and recalled from high school physics that the period of a linear pendulum is $2\pi\sqrt{L/g}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of looking at it, perhaps more physical.

First, with the usual "force" way of looking at the pendulum, we compute the restoring force in the tangential direction, $mg\sin\theta$. Letting $m=1$ we get a differential equation for $\theta$: $$\ddot{\theta} = -g\sin\theta$$ Using the approximation $\sin\theta\approx\theta$, valid for small $\theta$, we get the equation of simple harmonic motion (SHM), and a period that's independent of amplitude. Now $\sin\theta<\theta$ (except for $\theta=0$), so the actual restoring force is always a little bit less. Thus we expect it to take a little bit *longer* for a period than with SHM: as the pendulum bob passes the lowest point, the force trying to bring it back is a bit weaker than for the linear pendulum, so it will take longer for it to reverse direction.

Now let's compare with the derivation you describe. I would call this "energy-based". Notice first that $g(1-\cos\theta)$ is the potential energy of the pendulum:
[image: pendulum]

So $u$ is the fraction of the total energy $E$ that is kinetic: $$Eu = KE$$ $$E(1-u)=PE$$
Since the kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2}(L\dot{\theta})^2$ (setting $m=1$), we have $dt/d\theta = L/\sqrt{2KE}$, so the period is 
$$T = \int \frac{Ld\theta}{\sqrt{2Eu}} = \int \frac{Ldu}{\sqrt{2Eu}}\frac{d\theta}{du}$$
Leaving aside the constants, this is the formula you gave. To see this, note that the things inside the last two square roots of your formula are: $$1-u=\frac{g(1-\cos\theta)}{E}$$ and
$$1-\frac{E(1-u)}{2g} = \frac{1+\cos\theta}{2}$$ and so their product is $$\frac{g}{2E}(1-\cos\theta)(1+\cos\theta) = \frac{g}{2E}\sin^2\theta$$ Differentiating the formula $u=1-(g/E)(1-\cos\theta)$ gives $du = -(g/E)\sin\theta\,d\theta$, so the formulas are equivalent.

Now, key point: what approximation do we make in omitting the last factor? Essentially, $\cos\theta\approx 1$ for small $\theta$. Just like the approximation $\sin\theta\approx\theta$ used in the "force" derivation, this is a 1st order approximation. Since $\cos\theta<1$, the integrand for the actual pendulum will be larger than for the linear pendulum, and the period will be longer.

By the way, the integral for the non-linear case is an elliptic integral of the first kind. So it can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions (i.e., finite combinations of algebraic, trig, exponentials, and logs.)